# Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word error occuring when website is published

Tags: c#, asp.net, ms-word

I am replacing MS Word MergeFields with data from SQL Server in a simple asp.net c# application and it works fine locally but when i publish it i get the following:

```
System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x80080005): Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {00020906-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} failed due to the following error: 80080005.
```

I tried giving both `IIS_IUSRS` and `NETWORK SERVICE` full access, and also set the identity to interactive in the DCOM config but it didn't fix anything.

Comment: Try reading this article on how to correct these potential issues http://support.microsoft.com/kb/257757

Comment: Is word installed on the machine you are publishing to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should share the folder where you save the document that is created from the template  with the `NETWORK SERVICE` user.

Answer (score 0):

Server-side automation of Office is not recommended!

Read more about server-side automation in MS Office here: [Considerations for server-side Automation of Office](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/257757)